# Error message when trying to use Tufte-book

Tags: miktex, tufte-book

I am just using,

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}



\title{My Tufte Book}
\author{Your Name}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
This is the introduction to my Tufte-style book.

\section{Background}
Here is some background information.

\sidenote{This is a sidenote.}

\subsection{More Details}
Here are more details about the background.

\chapter{Methods}
This chapter describes the methods used in the study.

\backmatter
\chapter{Conclusion}
In conclusion, this Tufte Book example is quite basic.

\end{document}
```

and I am getting

```
hardwrap.sty
1
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \scan_stop: 
l.1
```

and

```
Package ifplatform Warning: 
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

)
(/Users/paulallen/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/generic
/iftex/ifxetex.sty) (
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \scan_stop: 
l.1 

?
```

I am using MikTex-texworks and it is all up to date, I have used it before but for some reason it's not working now. It renders in TexShop so I'm out of Ideas.

Sorry,

```
      This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex 2024.2.28)  23 MAR 2024 23:57
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tufte-latex/tufte-book.cls
Document Class: tufte-book 2015/06/21 v3.5.2 Tufte-book class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tufte-latex/tufte-common.def
File: tufte-common.def 2015/06/21 v3.5.2 Common code for the Tufte-LaTeX styles


(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks17
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks18

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count188
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xifthen/xifthen.sty
Package: xifthen 2015/11/05 v1.4.0 Extended ifthen features

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2023/07/08 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count189
\calc@Bcount=\count190
\calc@Adimen=\dimen140
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen141
\calc@Askip=\skip48
\calc@Bskip=\skip49
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count191
\calc@Cskip=\skip50
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifmtarg/ifmtarg.sty
Package: ifmtarg 2018/04/16 v1.2b check for an empty argument
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hardwrap/hardwrap.sty
Package: hardwrap 2011/02/12 v0.2 Hard wrap messages

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/07/08 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 77.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode is ignored in DVI mode.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)

Package ifplatform Warning: 
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\hw@charcount=\count192
\hw@wordcount=\count193
\hw@maxprintline=\count194

(|kpsewhich -var-value=max_print_line))
Class tufte-book Info: Loading the base class `book'

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count195
\c@chapter=\count196
\c@section=\count197
\c@subsection=\count198
\c@subsubsection=\count199
\c@paragraph=\count266
\c@subparagraph=\count267
\c@figure=\count268
\c@table=\count269
\abovecaptionskip=\skip51
\belowcaptionskip=\skip52
\bibindent=\dimen142
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty
Package: titlesec 2023/10/27 v2.16 Sectioning titles
\ttl@box=\box51
\beforetitleunit=\skip53
\aftertitleunit=\skip54
\ttl@plus=\dimen143
\ttl@minus=\dimen144
\ttl@toksa=\toks19
\titlewidth=\dimen145
\titlewidthlast=\dimen146
\titlewidthfirst=\dimen147
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titletoc.sty
Package: titletoc 2023/10/27 v2.16 TOC entries
\ttl@leftsep=\dimen148
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2023-11-26 v2.56 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count270
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count271
)
\@linkdim=\dimen149
\Hy@linkcounter=\count272
\Hy@pagecounter=\count273

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count274

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4062.
Package hyperref Info: Option `hyperfootnotes' set `false' on input line 4062.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4179.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4184.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4187.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4194.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4199.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4446.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count275

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4784.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen150

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count276
\Field@Width=\dimen151
\Fld@charsize=\dimen152
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6063.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6068.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6071.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6078.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6083.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6088.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6093.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count277
\c@Item=\count278
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
File: hdvips.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref driver for dvips

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
File: pdfmark.def 2024-01-20 v7.01h Hyperref definitions for pdfmark specials
\pdf@docset=\toks20
\pdf@box=\box52
\pdf@toks=\toks21
\pdf@defaulttoks=\toks22
\HyField@AnnotCount=\count279
\Fld@listcount=\count280
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count281

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend pac
kage
with kernel methods
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
85.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip55
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ragged2e/ragged2e.sty
Package: ragged2e 2023/06/22 v3.6 ragged2e Package
\CenteringLeftskip=\skip56
\RaggedLeftLeftskip=\skip57
\RaggedRightLeftskip=\skip58
\CenteringRightskip=\skip59
\RaggedLeftRightskip=\skip60
\RaggedRightRightskip=\skip61
\CenteringParfillskip=\skip62
\RaggedLeftParfillskip=\skip63
\RaggedRightParfillskip=\skip64
\JustifyingParfillskip=\skip65
\CenteringParindent=\skip66
\RaggedLeftParindent=\skip67
\RaggedRightParindent=\skip68
\JustifyingParindent=\skip69
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
\Gm@cnth=\count282
\Gm@cntv=\count283
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count284
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen153
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen154
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen155
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen156
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen157
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen158
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen159
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen160
\Gm@dimlist=\toks23
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changepage/changepage.sty
Package: changepage 2009/10/20 v1.0c check page and change page layout
\c@cp@cntr=\count285
\cp@tempcnt=\count286
)
\@tufte@overhang=\skip70
\@tufte@fullwidth=\skip71
\@tufte@caption@fill=\skip72

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/paralist/paralist.sty
Package: paralist 2017/01/22 v2.7 Extended list environments
\pltopsep=\skip73
\plpartopsep=\skip74
\plitemsep=\skip75
\plparsep=\skip76
\pl@lab=\toks24
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2023/07/27 v1.04 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
Package textcase Info: Defining Legacy names on input line 20.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/soul/soul.sty
Package: soul 2023-06-14 v3.1 Permit use of UTF-8 characters in soul (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/soul/soul-ori.sty
Package: soul-ori 2023-06-14 v3.1 letterspacing/underlining (mf)
\SOUL@word=\toks25
\SOUL@lasttoken=\toks26
\SOUL@syllable=\toks27
\SOUL@cmds=\toks28
\SOUL@buffer=\toks29
\SOUL@token=\toks30
\SOUL@syllgoal=\dimen161
\SOUL@syllwidth=\dimen162
\SOUL@charkern=\dimen163
\SOUL@hyphkern=\dimen164
\SOUL@dimen=\dimen165
\SOUL@dimeni=\dimen166
\SOUL@minus=\count287
\SOUL@comma=\count288
\SOUL@apo=\count289
\SOUL@grave=\count290
\SOUL@spaceskip=\skip77
\SOUL@ttwidth=\dimen167
\SOUL@uldp=\dimen168
\SOUL@ulht=\dimen169
))
LaTeX Info: Redefining \allcapsspacing on input line 737.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smallcapsspacing on input line 737.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2022/12/04 v6.7b set line spacing
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)

Package xcolor Warning: Package option `usenames' is obsolete and ignored on in
put line 266.

Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 274.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2022/09/22 v3.1e Graphics/color driver for dvips
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def
File: dvipsnam.def 2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/svgnam.def
File: svgnam.def 2023/11/15 v3.01 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip78
\bibsep=\skip79
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count291
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/bibentry.sty
Package: bibentry 2007/10/30 1.5 (PWD)
)
No file test.bbl.
\c@@tufte@num@bibkeys=\count292
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sauerj/optparams.sty
Package: optparams 2004/08/14 v0.9 multiple optional parameters in macros
)
\@tufte@sidenote@vertical@offset=\skip80

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty
Package: placeins 2005/04/18  v 2.2
)
\@tufte@margin@floatbox=\box53
\@tufte@figure@box=\box54
\@tufte@caption@box=\box55
\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset=\skip81
\@tufte@float@contents@width=\skip82

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty
Package: mathpazo 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
\symupright=\mathgroup4
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty
Package: helvet 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 (WaS) 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bera/beramono.sty
Package: beramono 2004/01/31 (WaS)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+pplj on input line 1
12.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pplj.fd
File: t1pplj.fd 2004/09/06 font definitions for T1/pplj.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2022/11/09 v4.1 Extensive control of page headers and footers

\f@nch@headwidth=\skip83
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip84
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip85
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip86
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip87
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip88
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip89
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip90
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip91
)
\tufteskipamount=\skip92

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty
Package: multicol 2023/03/30 v1.9f multicolumn formatting (FMi)
\c@tracingmulticols=\count293
\mult@box=\box56
\multicol@leftmargin=\dimen170
\c@unbalance=\count294
\c@collectmore=\count295
\doublecol@number=\count296
\multicoltolerance=\count297
\multicolpretolerance=\count298
\full@width=\dimen171
\page@free=\dimen172
\premulticols=\dimen173
\postmulticols=\dimen174
\multicolsep=\skip93
\multicolbaselineskip=\skip94
\partial@page=\box57
\last@line=\box58
\mc@boxedresult=\box59
\maxbalancingoverflow=\dimen175
\mult@rightbox=\box60
\mult@grightbox=\box61
\mult@firstbox=\box62
\mult@gfirstbox=\box63
\@tempa=\box64
\@tempa=\box65
\@tempa=\box66
\@tempa=\box67
\@tempa=\box68
\@tempa=\box69
\@tempa=\box70
\@tempa=\box71
\@tempa=\box72
\@tempa=\box73
\@tempa=\box74
\@tempa=\box75
\@tempa=\box76
\@tempa=\box77
\@tempa=\box78
\@tempa=\box79
\@tempa=\box80
\@tempa=\box81
\@tempa=\box82
\@tempa=\box83
\@tempa=\box84
\@tempa=\box85
\@tempa=\box86
\@tempa=\box87
\@tempa=\box88
\@tempa=\box89
\@tempa=\box90
\@tempa=\box91
\@tempa=\box92
\@tempa=\box93
\@tempa=\box94
\@tempa=\box95
\@tempa=\box96
\@tempa=\box97
\@tempa=\box98
\@tempa=\box99
\c@minrows=\count299
\c@columnbadness=\count300
\c@finalcolumnbadness=\count301
\last@try=\dimen176
\multicolovershoot=\dimen177
\multicolundershoot=\dimen178
\mult@nat@firstbox=\box100
\colbreak@box=\box101
\mc@col@check@num=\count302
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2024-02-20 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box102
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count303
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box103
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box104
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count304
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count305
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count306
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 8.
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `test.out'.


Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: dvips
* paper: letterpaper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside asymmetric 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 312.0pt, 230.02501pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 616.0pt, 106.7pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=312.0pt
* \textheight=616.0pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-42.0pt
* \headheight=14.0pt
* \headsep=28.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=25.29494pt
* \marginparwidth=144.0pt
* \marginparsep=24.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
```

Comment: your example runs on an up to date texlive, you probably have old versions of expl3 or a package in your path but you haven't shown enough of the log to know.

Comment: oh actually it's trying to run `\input{|kpsewhich -var-value=max_print_line}` does that work on miktex? sorry I don't have miktex to test. Someone here will be able to check.

Comment: works ok for me on miktex. Show the complete log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer not sure if that the best way to show the log here but there it is.

Comment: @PaulA The log file doesn't show errors.

Comment: `usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist` that's texlive not miktex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is the only log file I have

Comment: if you are running texlive and miktex on the same file they will over-write the log each time, so you will need to re-run miktex to generate the log with the error.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle is this the one you need?

Comment: it looks like that is the terminal output not the log so it has the paths (which look ok) but not the package versions the log has additional lines such as `Package: hardwrap 2011/02/12 v0.2 Hard wrap messages`

Comment: also try renaming you main file not to have a space in its name

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this is the full log file after I have ran it through MixTex only. Its it not over-writing because its not compiling and still showing the livetex? I have renamed it and it hasn't produced a log file.

Comment: How do you manage to get sometimes a miktex and sometimes a texlive output? And if texlive works then why don't you simply stick to it?

Comment: You just changed it back!!!  with texlive your log starts `**"Draft 4.tex"` so you are cd to the directory with that file then run `pdflatex "Draft 4"`  with the miktex log (which is what you should be showing but you deleted) your log started something like `(/some/path/to/draft 4.tex`  which means that you were not cd to the document directory instead you (or your editor) are doing `pdftex /some/path/to/draft 4.tex`  which means the log will be wherever you were when you ran pdftex (probably your editor or miktex's application folder, i don't know)

Comment: but what you are showing from miktex was not a log file, just the terminal output, and what you are showing from texlive is unrelated to your question about miktex

Comment: I have just run it through a terminal to get a log file and this is it.

Comment: sorry It's gone midnight and I give up. The question as it is currently is not answerable as you are asking about an error on miktex but showing an error free run using a completely different program.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , thanks anyway Will take another look with fresh eyes tomorrow.

Comment: "I have just run **it**"  you ran texlive pdftex which is a completely different program to the one your question is asking about, which is miktex pdftex.

Comment: why do you have two tex systems installed, can't you just use the one that works?

Comment: Easiest solution is likely to configure TeXworks to use TeX Live and get rid of MikTeX.